# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope Error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am getting this common error  Error: `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope` with my test case . I know this is a common one , and there are few other threads explaining with solutions . But i really couldn't come up with a answer to my problem . Can anyone point me in the right direction?

ViewMeetingCtrl ,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('MyApp').controller('ViewMeetingCtrl', ViewMeetingCtrl);

    ViewMeetingCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$http', '$translate', 'notificationService', 'meetingService', '$modal', 'meeting', 'attachmentService'];

    function ViewMeetingCtrl($scope, $state, $http, $translate, notificationService, meetingService, $modal, meeting, attachmentService) {
        $scope.meeting = meeting;
        $scope.test = "testvalue";
        if (meeting.Status == 'Cancelled')
        {
            $scope.actionButtons = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.actionButtons = true;
        }

        //more code
    }
})();
```

MeetingCtrlSpec.js

```
describe('ViewMeetingCtrl', function () {
    var $rootScope, scope, $controller, meetingService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('MyApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, meetingService) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('ViewMeetingCtrl', {
            meetingService: meetingService,
            '$rootScope' : $rootScope,
            scope: scope
        });       

    }));

    it('should change greeting value if name value is changed', function () {
        //some assertion
    });
});
```

Error trace :

```
Firefox 37.0.0 (Windows 8.1) ViewMeetingCtrl should change greeting value if name value is changed FAILED
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ViewMeetingCtrl
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20ViewMeetingCtrl

        minErr/<@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
        createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/ang
ular/angular.js:4015:19
        getService@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4162:39
        createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/ang
ular/angular.js:4020:28
        getService@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4162:39
        invoke@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4194:1
        instantiate@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4211:27
        $ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/an
gular.js:8501:18
        angular.mock.$ControllerDecorator</<@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/node_modules/angular-mo
cks/angular-mocks.js:1878:12
        @C:/Users/dell pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/FLIS.Client.Tests/test/company/MeetingCtrlSpec.js:8:1
        invoke@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4203:14
        workFn@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2436:11
        angular.mock.inject@C:/Users/dell%20pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/WebApiRole/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks
.js:2407:25
        @C:/Users/dell pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/Client.Tests/test/company/MeetingCtrlSpec.js:6:16
        @C:/Users/dell pc/Documents/Work/MyApp/Client.Tests/test/company/MeetingCtrlSpec.js:1:1
Firefox 37.0.0 (Windows 8.1): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.094 secs / 0.091 secs)
```

Comment: Typo! It should be `$scope: scope` you missed a dollar and no need to inject `$rootScope` since you are not dependent though that is not the issue.

Comment: @PSL , much obliged for your response . that solved my issue , but ultimately lead to another one . It says `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: meetingProvider <- meeting <- ViewMeetingCtrl` . can you give something for this error ? Because i don't have anything called meetingProvider anywhere in my solution .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
    $controller('ViewMeetingCtrl', {
        meetingService: meetingService,
        '$rootScope' : $rootScope,
        scope: scope
    });
```

by

```
    $controller('ViewMeetingCtrl', {
        meetingService: meetingService,
        $scope: scope
    });
```

The controller must be injected with an argument named $scope, not scope. And $rootScope is not part of the injected collaborators of your controller.

Comment: thank you for your response . however , the modified test case gives me another error saying `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: meetingProvider <- meeting <- ViewMeetingCtrl` . But i don't have anything called meetingProvider . ?

Comment: That just means that you haven't loaded any module containing a service named 'meeting'. Every service has an associated provider (even if not explicitely defined)

Comment: `ViewMeetingCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$http', '$translate', 'notificationService', 'meetingService', '$modal', 'meeting', 'attachmentService'];
`
those are the dependencies i inject in the ctrl . does that mean i need to inject them in the test case too ?

Comment: No. That means that since your controller depends on a service named 'meeting', this service must exist. If it exists, angular will inject it.

Answer (score 0):

Same error I had forget to put `'$'` before `scope` in

```
app.controller("loginCtrl", function(**$**scope){

})
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please do not add an answer that just repeats an already existing one. Instead, upvote the one that is already there. I know that for the moment you don't have enough rep for that (15), but in this case the best approach is to bookmark this page and, when you have enough rep, come back here and upvote. Otherwise, as frustrating as it may be (we've all been there!), just let it go. But please do not post an answer that doesn't add anything to what is already there. Thank you!